# Program "/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build" is not found in PATH

Tags: android, eclipse, path

I imported an existing Android project to my Eclipse.
I get an error in the project that prevents me from building:
I get this message in "problems":

Program "/opt/adt-bundle-linux/android-ndk-r8e/ndk-build" is not found in PATH

and the problem type is: C/C++ Problem.
I have a windows machine with Eclipse (ADT) and Java up to date and I suspect that the original project where this project was built, is different (perhaps it is Linux?), or perhaps it makes use of native code and my Eclispe is not configued to support it. I don't have such an issue with other projects in my Eclipse...

Please, advise....
thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is a result of a project configured for an extremely specific NDK installation on a Linux box. You will need to find the configuration item calling that out and change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Chris Stratton stated, this project is made on a Linux machine. 
You can change your PATH if you go to: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build -> Environment

You can edit PATH there. After you've deleted that "/opt/.." you should add the path of your own ndk-build. If you don't know what ndk-build is take a look over here: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html